# Deploy Angular 5 build:ssr on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, angular5, server-side-rendering

I've built my project starting form the angular universal template found here:
[universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

I am trying to deploy the ssr build as azure web app. My code is on VSTS.

On my local machine I can run the following:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run build:ssr`. This produces the dist folder.
3. I can then copy the dist folder somewhere else and run with the command below
4. `node server.js`

The app starts on port 4000 on local machine.

So following the steps above, I've created a build process on my VSTS with the following tasks:

1. An npm task that runs `npm install`
2. An npm task that run `npm run build:ssr`
3. An azure app service deploy task with the following configurations:

   - Package Folder: dist/
   - web.config parameters: -Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node

Above process runs successfully, but when I navigate to **https://my-site-name.azurewebsites.net/** the site cannot be reached.

How can I successfully deploy Angular 5 SSR on Azure?

**UPDATE:**
Since this [NodeJS-EmptySiteTemplate](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/NodeJS-EmptySiteTemplate) runs on azure without error, I've done the following changes as per that project:

1. That server is listening on process.env.PORT | 8080
2. There was a web.config file there that I was missing. I placed the same web-config file in the wwwroot.

But not I am getting: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Having so much difficulties I have had to take a different approach (deploy in docker) instead. I'd still like to test your suggestion below sometime soon and mark it as answered if it works.

Comment: I have added a detailed description on what you can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you are using current directory as working folder instead of add additional `dist` folder (`const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');`).

You can enable diagnostics logs of that app service and check the detail logs, it still looks for index view in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\dist\browser`, so it is incorrect and will throw 500 error.

BTW: the port is 80 (`process.env.PORT`) instead of 4000.

Update:

The `server.ts` requires module files in `dist` folder, so just change `DIST_FOLDER` is not working. The simple way is putting server.js out of dist folder (Do not modify server.ts).

Simple steps:

1. Open webpack.server.config.js
2. Replace path: `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')` to `path:__dirname`
3. NPM Install task
4. NPM Custom task (run build:ssr)
5. Copy Files task (Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist`; Contents: `**`; Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist`)
6. Copy Files task (Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`; Contents: `server.js` `prerender.js` (**one per a line**)
7. Azure App Service Deploy task (Package or folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app`; Webconfig parameters: `-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node`)

Comment: I have changed my project so that it doesn't require an additional dist folder. I also tried port 4000 with no luck.

I've also created an empty nodejs template web-app and that runs find. So I checked out the source from here to see the difference:
https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/NodeJS-EmptySiteTemplate

That server is listening on process.env.PORT | 8080, so I did the same. There is a web.config file there that I was missing. I placed the same web-config file in the wwwroot but not I am getting:
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: What's the target folder on step 6? same as 5? Another thing is server.js and prerender.js is in the generated dist folder not in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist. So do we need this step?

Comment: Here's the zipped `dist` folder:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R5WMDvkgfUr_x1JsGURfQI0Bp-yGqNf7

This is just built from Universal Starter repo (https://github.com/angular/universal-starter), applying the change to webpack.server.config.js as you mentioned, running with build:ssr

Comment: @Kayes The target folder for step 6 is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app`, which is used to copy `server.js` and `prerender.js` to app folder (out of dist folder). After that there are dist folder, server.js and prerender.js in app folder.

Answer (score 3):

After spending many hours on this, I am going to expand on Starians answer. Although it did eventually help me get azure working, there were bits of information missing or incorrect.
So, I am going to try to do a step by step walk though.

> The first thing to note, is that I do not change any file to get this to work.
>   If you change **webpack.server.config.js** then when you do a local `build:ssr` it will create **server.js** in your root application folder, which is undesirable.

So, if you are using the azure visual designer, you can follow these steps:

- First, connect to your repository and setup the branch you wish to use
- Add the **Node Tool Installer** task and set it to use the current version of node
- Add an **npm** task and set the **Command** to custom; Set the **Command and arguments** to `install @angular/cli -g` (name it "npm install angular cli")
- Add another **npm** task but keep it on install (name it something like "npm install packages")
- Add a **Command Line** task and set the script to `npm run build:ssr` (name it "build the project")
- Add a **Copy files** task, set the **Source folder** to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist`, the **Contents** to `**` and the **Target folder** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist` (name it something like "Copy dist files to staging"
- Add another **Copy files** task, set the **Source folder** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist`, the **Contents** to `server.js` and the **Target folder** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app` (name this something like "Copy server.js to the root")
- Then add a **Delete Files** task, set the **Source folder** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist` and the **Contents** to `server.js` (name this something like "Delete the dist/server.js"
- Finally, add an **Azure App Service Deploy** task, set the **Package or folder** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app`

  - Find the **File Transforms & Variable Substituion Options**, make sure **Generate Web.config** is selected and add these **Web.config parameters**: `-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node`

If you follow that guide properly, you should end up with a folder structure similar to:

> web.config
>
> server.js
>
> dist

and the `dist` folder should contain two more folders (browser and server).
If that is the case (and it should be) you will have a working **Angular Universal** application.

For those that would like it, here is the **yml**:

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: npm

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 8.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 8.x


- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install angular cli'
  inputs:
    command: custom

    verbose: false

    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli -g'


- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install packages'
  inputs:
    verbose: false


- script: 'npm run build:ssr'
  displayName: 'build the project'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy dist files to staging'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'

    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'


- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy server.js to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

    Contents: server.js

    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'


- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete the dist/server.js'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

    Contents: server.js


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription 1'

    WebAppName: website

    DeployToSlotFlag: true

    ResourceGroupName: Temp

    SlotName: master

    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'

    GenerateWebConfig: true

    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'

    UseWebDeploy: true

    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

I hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: forgot zip task.