# How to deploy angular universal app in azureDevOps app service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal, angular8

I'm facing a problem deploying an angular universal app in azure web service I followed this step https://stackoverflow.com/a/53616516/10979521 but a got an error says

```
##[error]Error: Publish using webdeploy options are supported only when using Windows agent.
```

I guess the issue occurs in creating an app service, in my app service settings
    (
           *publish  (code)
           *runtime stack (.NET Core 2.2)
            *Operating System (Windows)
    )

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build:ssr
  displayName: 'build the project'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy dist files to staging'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'

    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'


- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy server.js to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

    Contents: server.js

    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete the dist/server.js'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

    Contents: server.js

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my subscription'
    WebAppName: 'my website'
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
    GenerateWebConfig: true
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
    UseWebDeploy: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

Comment: Provide the detail log of build the project task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2 (9/3/2020)**
Microsoft is moving away from release pipelines.

"Classic Release Pipelines"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops

New "Pipelines"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2

**Edit:**

I realized after I typed this up that maybe your problem is you have "UseWebDeploy: true" and maybe you can fix your problem by setting this to false.  Below is a screenshot taken from the same task setup in a release pipeline.

[image]

I still think your best option is to remove the deploy task from your build pipeline as outlined below since build pipelines are not meant to be used in this way.  But that is up to you.

**Original Answer:**

Remove this part from your build pipeline:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my subscription'
    WebAppName: 'my website'
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
    GenerateWebConfig: true
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
    UseWebDeploy: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

Add a publish step to the end of you build.yml file.  This will allow your release pipeline to pick up the artifacts from your build.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

**Setup a release pipeline to deploy your build.**

[image]

- Create a new pipeline
- Add the artifact from your build
  [image]
- Then add a stage (ie Dev, QA, Production)
- Select "empty job"
- Edit the stage and add tasks
- Add the Azure App Service task
  [image]
- Update the version number on the Azure App Service Deploy to version 3 (the same one you are using in your yaml - AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3).
- Fill in the values in the task the same way you have it in your yaml.

The default value for the "Package or folder" option probably isn't correct.  You can use the 3 dots on the right to navigate and select the correct folder.  If you click this and see nothing then this is most likely because you haven't kicked off a build yet with the above "PublishBuildArtifact@1" change.
[image]

Keep working your way down and expanding the options to find your other configuration settings.
[image]
[image]

If you are having trouble with anything you can verify the task is setup properly by scrolling to the top of the task and clicking "View YAML".  Then you can compare to your original yaml.
[image]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I try to change vmImage at your suggested but I got this error                                      
   ##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: d:\a\1\s\dist   Thank you for your response

Comment: @PaoloDionisio Updated my answer.  Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: (7/16/2019 3:12:11 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\browser'.
Error: The error code was 0x80070002.
Error: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\browser'.

Comment: at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
Error count: 1.
Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295

Comment: Hello @Ryan E. I followed your answer and I got this Error. I created a CD release

Comment: BTW Thank you for your answer

Comment: @PaoD. what value do you have the "Package Folder" property set to in the Azure App Service Deploy task?

Comment: - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: webiste'
  inputs:
  azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
    WebAppName: 'webiste'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/website-angular (1)/drop/dist'
    GenerateWebConfig: true
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
    UseWebDeploy: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000'
    RenameFilesFlag: true
  enabled: false

Comment: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/website-angular (1)/drop/dist'

Comment: Looks like your path may be off a bit. You are copying files to /app/dist and /app in your build.  In your original release yaml step you are deploying /app so your path should be '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/website-angular (1)/drop/app'.  I also personally would rename the /website-angular (1) part by editing your pipeline -> click on your artifact -> change the source alias to _MyWebsite. Then your final path would be $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyWebsite/drop/app.

Comment: If the path doesn't fix it, looks like you may have to shut down the app service.  More details on issue here - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4143

Comment: "since build pipelines are not meant to be used in this way" - this is outdated suggestion, as Azure DevOps is moving away from "Releases" and advocates for deployments inside the "Pipelines", hence the same yaml files, as "deployment" tasks.

Comment: Link?  Seems wacky to me that they are moving away from release pipelines.  Although I do know they have been trying to integrate yaml into the release pipelines.

Comment: Updated answer.  If you have any other links you think would be helpful let me know!