# Hosting Laravel 8 on Azure Web Service (window container) -> cannot write within wwwroot

Tags: azure-web-app-service, laravel-8, readonly

I try to run Laravel 8 on Azure Web Service, very close to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-windows). I used the windows container because of the possibility to change the document root to Laravel's /public by justify the virtual application path (not supported for linux).

So far, so good...

My problem is that Laravel tries on different places (logging, etc...) to write in its directories but this seams to be read-only

This is the original document root in azure web app
./wwwroot

I could change the virtual application path but this made anything below 'public' read-only and laravel needs to write in it
./wwwroot/public

Sure, I could run it as default and write .htaccessre-write rules to ./public. However this is not realy what I want and what Laravel's request lifecycle was made for.

e.g.:

```php
fwrite(): write of 2073 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor
\wwwroot\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:134
```

I'm thankfully for any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039520/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-app-in-azuredevops-app-service). Thanks to [Ryan E.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7998137/ryan-e)